# PHP / SQL Server: PHP Notice: Undefined index: and PHP Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php, sql-server

I have something weird about my system. Currently, I developed a system that enables users to update the photo by choose from files and upload to the database.

The problem is after I click "Please select" to select the photo and click "Upload", an alert will show "Photo updated!" when I click "OK" on that alert, it will display:

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: report_id in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker_testing\pages\dashboard\engineer\view_task\view_task.php on line 7

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: report_date in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker_testing\pages\dashboard\engineer\view_task\view_task.php on line 178

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ot_start in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker_testing\pages\dashboard\engineer\view_task\view_task.php on line 182

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ot_end in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker_testing\pages\dashboard\engineer\view_task\view_task.php on line 185

.....

But, when I check at the database, the photo updated! Can I know why?

Below is my code.

```
<?php

  require_once "../../../../config/configPDO.php";
  require_once "../../../../config/check.php";
  $team_n = $_SESSION['team_n'];

  $report_id = $_GET['report_id'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid LEFT JOIN ot_team ON ot_team.team_id = ot_users.team_id WHERE report_id = :report_id";
  $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));
  while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

      $report_id = $row["report_id"];
      $report_date = $row["report_date"];
      $task_name = $row["task_name"];
      $photo_before = $row["photo_before"];
      $photo_after = $row["photo_after"];
      $ot_start = $row["ot_start"];
      $ot_end = $row["ot_end"];
      $time_photo_before = $row["time_photo_before"];
      $time_photo_after = $row["time_photo_after"];
      $report_status = $row["report_status"];

  }

?>

               <table align="center" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="20%"><b>Date Report</b></td>
                    <td width="80%" colspan='3'><?php echo $report_date; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <form action="update_task_name.php" method="POST">
                    <td><b>Task Name</b></td>
                    <td colspan = '2'><input type="text" class="form-control" name="task_name" value="<?php echo $task_name; ?>"/></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $report_id ?>"> 
                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value = "Save" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')"></td>
                    </form>
                  </tr>
                  <form action="update_photo_before.php" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <tr>
                    <td rowspan = '3'><b>Before Task</b></td>

                    <?php
                      if(!isset($photo_before) || empty($photo_before)) {
                          echo "<td colspan='2' rowspan='2'><img src='../../../../images/faces/noimage.png'/></td>";
                        }else{ 
                                echo "<td colspan='2' rowspan='2'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$photo_before."'/></td>"; 
                        }
                    ?>

                    <td colspan ='2'><input type="file" name="uploadFile" value="" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $report_id ?>"> 
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')"/></td>

                  </tr>
                  </form>
                  <tr>

                  <?php
                      if($time_photo_before == null) {
                          $time_photo_before = " -";
                        }else{}
                    ?>
                    <td colspan='3'><?php echo "Time: <b>" .$time_photo_before."</b>"; ?></td>
                  <tr>
                    <td rowspan = '3'><b>After Task</b></td>
                    <?php
                      if(!isset($photo_after) || empty($photo_after)) {
                          echo "<td colspan='2' rowspan='2'><img src='../../../../images/faces/noimage.png'/></td>";
                        }else{ 
                                echo "<td colspan='2' rowspan='2'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".$photo_after."'/></td>"; 
                        }
                    ?>
                      <td colspan ='2'></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <?php
                      if($time_photo_after == null) {
                          $time_photo_after = " -";
                        }else{}
                    ?>
                    <td colspan='3'><?php echo "Time: <b>" .$time_photo_after."</b>"; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><b>OT - From</b></td>
                    <td><?php echo $ot_start; ?></td>
                    <form action="update_ot_start.php" method="POST">
                    <td width ='35%'>
                        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="ot_start">
                          <option value="12:00" <?php echo $ot_start == '12:00'? 'selected': '';?> >12:00</option>
                          <option value="12:30" <?php echo $ot_start == '12:30'? 'selected': '';?> >12:30</option>
                          <option value="13:00" <?php echo $ot_start == '13:00'? 'selected': '';?> >13:00</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $report_id ?>">  
                    </td>
                    <td width ='30%'><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value = "Save" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')"></td>
                    </form>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><b>OT - To</b></td>
                    <td width ='35%'><?php echo $ot_end; ?>
                    </td>
                    <form action="update_ot_end.php" method="POST">
                    <td width ='35%'>
                        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="ot_end">
                          <option value="15:30" <?php echo $ot_end == '15:30'? 'selected': '';?> >15:30</option>
                          <option value="16:00" <?php echo $ot_end == '16:00'? 'selected': '';?> >16:00</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="<?php echo $report_id ?>">  
                    </td>
                    <td width ='30%'><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value = "Save" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?')"></td>
                    </form>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><b>Report Status</b></td>

                    <?php

                      if($report_status=="Pending")
                      {
                          $color="color:blue";
                      }
                      else 
                      {
                          $color="color:green";
                      }

                      echo "<td style='$color' colspan='3'><strong>" . $report_status ."</strong></td>"; 
                    ?>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

update_photo_before.php

```
<?php

    require_once '../../../../config/configPDO.php';

    if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'])) {
    //Allowed file type
    $allowed_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

    //File extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    //Check extension
    if(in_array($ext, $allowed_extensions)) {
        //Convert image to base64
        $encoded_image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']));
        $encoded_image = $encoded_image;
        $query = "UPDATE ot_report SET photo_before = '$encoded_image' WHERE report_id = :report_id";
        $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
        $sql->bindParam(':report_id', $_POST['report_id']);
        $sql -> execute();

        echo "File name : " . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
        echo "<br>";
        if($sql->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        echo "
        <script>alert('Photo updated!')</script>
        <script>window.location = 'view_task.php'</script>
        ";
        $last_insert_id = $conn-> lastInsertId(); 
        } else {
        echo "
        <script>alert('Fail to updated')</script>
        <script>window.location = 'view_task.php'</script>
        ";
        }
    } else {
        echo "File not allowed";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: @Jeto no sir...

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need `!isset($photo_before) || empty($photo_before)` because `empty($photo_before)` will cover both checks.

Comment: @RadamelFalcao Well, it should, as it's a very basic/common error. Anyway, request variables don't persist between requests. Your JS redirect loses the `$_POST` values.

Comment: @Jeto can u reedit my code, i didnt understand

Comment: Only fields that exist inside of the `<form>` tags will be submitted.  What does `var_export($_POST);` say?  That hidden field looks like it is violating valid html.

Comment: @RadamelFalcao You're posting a form to `update_photo_before.php`. There, your `$_POST` variables are available. Then you do `window.location = 'view_task.php'` (JS). But request variables won't be passed to it, as it's another request. Anyway that's for `request_id`, no idea about the other ones since they're not anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I already update my question

Comment: @Jeto check my latest code above

Comment: `report_id` is `POST`ed, so use `$_POST`, not `$_GET`.

Comment: @mickmackusa at which line?

Comment: Maybe I am looking at the wrong script `$report_id = $_GET['report_id'];`  what does `var_export($_POST);` show you?